# Is the composition of two linear functions is a linear function?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $2$ linear functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ would the $g(f(x))$ be a linear function as well?
An example I wrote out was: $f(x) = 3x_1+4x_2$ and $g(x) = 7x_1+8x_2$

Is $g(f(x)) = 7(3x_1+4x_2)+8(3x_1+4x_2)= 21x_1+28x_2+24x_1+32x_2= 45x_1+60x_2$? If I'm wrong, can you please explain the reasoning as to why?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $f:U \to V$ and $g:W \to U$ are two linear functions, where $U,V,W$ are vector spaces over a field $k$.  Then

$$f\circ g(w_1 + w_2) = f(g(w_1 + w_2)) = f(g(w_1) + g(w_2)) = f(g(w_1)) + f(g(w_2)) = f\circ g(w_1) + f\circ g(w_2)$$ where $w_i \in W$.

Similarly, for $\lambda \in k$, $$f\circ g(\lambda w) = f(g(\lambda w)) = f(\lambda g(w)) = \lambda f(g(w)) = \lambda f\circ g(w)$$ for every $w \in W$.

Thus, $f\circ g$ is also a linear function

Comment: Thank you for responding. In an attempt to explain your answer to myself, the way I might've done it is incorrect and that it should actually be 7(3x_1)+8(4x_2) right?

Comment: I think the issue with your example is that $f$ and $g$ have the same domain and codomain.  For example, if you are working over $\mathbb R$, then $f,g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.  Thus it doesn't make sense to compose them.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include the domain. I know that f: R^n-> R and g: R->R.